# Detect user's gesture such as swipe

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, gesture-recognition

I am using phonegap for build android apps.

I would like to detect user's gesture such as a user's swipe. Is there an event i can call  from javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use a JavaScript framework called [xui](http://github.com/xui/xui) ([homepage](http://xuijs.com)) that has a similar API to jQuery.

You can use this framework coupled with [the swipe plugin](https://github.com/xui/xui-plugins) to get access to easy gesture events. See the swipe/ directory under that repository for the code and example (specifically under index.html). A brief example:

```
x$('body').swipe(function(e, data) {
    console.log('type:' + data.type + ' deltaX:' + data.deltaX + ' deltaY:' + data.deltaY + ' distance:' + data.distance + ' delay:' + data.delay+' direction:' + data.direction  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate. this was what i was looking for! sorry for being greedy.. but isit also possible to include to detect custom gesture? such as when a user draw a 'C' or'S'? Thankss!

Comment: with this plugin, unfortunately not. you would have to edit it. After a brief look at the code, it looks like the swipe plugins keeps track of start and end coordinates. For more complex gestures, you'd have to change the code to keep track of several "points" during a gesture (with a short interval timeout, for example), and then compare the coordinates of the various points to conclude something more meaningful about the full gesture after the touchend even fires. hope that helps.

Comment: ok sure thanks :D i will look into the codes in detailed.. any idea if i can track the gesture only at a certain area? i.e at the top of the screen..meaning i sort of seperate the screen into half. :D

Comment: there is another library, also called jGestures, which is designed specifically for custom gestures - you define the shapes and it will tell you when the user does something similar to one of the shapes. see here: http://stanford.wikia.com/wiki/CS349W_Project3_jGestures

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) also provides basic [support for gestures](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html) (at least tap, long tap and swipe left&right).

Some additional plugins can be found on the [Resources site](http://jquerymobile.com/resources/#Plugins). Maybe there are more of them on the [plugin site](http://plugins.jquery.com).